# SIP invite is not received until 180 seconds

Tags: asterisk, voip, sipml

I am using asterisk 11.9 + Chrome 56.0 + SIPML5,
Scenario:
 
1. Chrome receives "new_call" event from asterisk, it renders ringing icon on the screen
2. Do not answer the call, press F5 or CTRL+F5 to refresh the browser
3. Wait for 180 seconds, "new_call" event is received again on chrome

To tackle above 180 seconds restriction:
I changed asterisk's queue timeout to 2 seconds, I can receive an invite after every 2 seconds but the sequence number or sip session is changed in every invite and when I answer the call, it sometimes tells me "SIP session is not valid"

So, is there any possible way so that I can configure "asterisk or call Queue"
to send the old invite again frequently.(In every 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

No, queue know nothing about channel driver and can't do that.

But you can use conference&forver call from conference to your browser, if you think that can help you.

Comment: there are two end clients (two browsers), if any one of them picks up the call, it will disappear from the 2nd browser, Can I still use conference?

Comment: that depend of how you are orginized dialplan.